# Column Foreign key is of type bigint but expression is of type uuid in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, uuid

I want to use `UUIDField` for primary key. This is my model:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=124)
```

All things is good. But when I want to use `id` of `Organization` model for `ForeignKey` in this model:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    reference = models.ForeignKey('Organization', null=True,  on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=124)
```

I got this error:

```
    django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "reference" is of type bigint but expression is of type uuid
    LINE 1: "reference" = 'af104709-...
                          ^
    HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

**What can I do?**